# What is the relation between Light (Suryadevta) and Air (Vayu)?

Tags: surya, vayu

Sun is the Devata (Deity/Surya Deva) of Air (Vayu) and Sun travels on Air (vayu) as its chariot (Vayu rupi rath). If there is no air can the sun rays have speed?

Comment: there is no air in space, yet sunlight travels from 90 million miles away to earth

Comment: Light can travel trough all kinds of mediums. Your question is therefore not interesting. "Sun is the Devata (Deity/Surya Deva) of Air" no the sun is NOT the deva of air. Surya deva rules the sun and Vayu deva controls the air.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu any proof from any scripture? Your personal thoughts are not acceptable here.

Comment: These are no personal thoughts just objective facts. Your question is actually confusing.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu then wait for an answer. The question is correct. Is absolute vacuum exist? Google it. If not then air is everywhere.

Comment: @ram see my above comment.

Comment: There is no need for an answer since light travels without air as numerous stories in hindiusm prove.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu please write an answer. I will be blessed!

Comment: @SumitSharma Both these gods might be interdependent on each other to support life, but I haven't read of any such relationship between these two. As this discussion has become somewhat fact-based, If you wish, I can help you with a logical answer.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal  Go on with your answer

Comment: @SumitSharma First of all, science-based answers are not allowed here, so I am providing this as a comment only.
The wind blows due to the temperature difference created by the Sun. (e.g. Land becomes hot, while the air above Oceans remains relatively cooler, this causes a pressure difference and causes wind).
On the other hand, In the absence of Atmosphere (air/vayu), direct sunlight is dangerous for life. Refer http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/7f.html. 
With this, we can assume, how both of these interact to support life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun is the Devata (Deity/Surya Deva) of Vayu as "Sun’s Chariot" travels in "Air" which symbolizes "Air" (Vayu) as "chariot" on which Sun (Surya Deva) travels.

The movement of the chariot of the sun: **By the force of Air (Pravaha Vāyu)**, the Sun God, the Incarnate of the Vedas travels round the cities, the Zodiac, in one Samvatsara (year) [The Devi Bhagavata Purana(book 8, chapter 15)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57303.html)

**Theoretically:**

Sun-rays (Tej) is tangible.
Earth, Water and Fire have a form. They are called Tangible.
Air (Vayu) and Ether (Akash) do not have a tangible form that is why we feel Sun rays are faster.
But the enabler of speed in Sunrays is Air (Vayu).

So if there is no air, can the sun rays have speed? If Air (Vayu) would not exist, if it does not combine with the Sunrays how would the rays come?

**Answer what Scriptures say:**

But before that we need to know that is there any place which is devoid of air? Or any place [**where absolute vacuum exist**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161107/why-is-it-impossible-to-have-a-perfect-vacuum)?

Wherever there is movement you have to accept the presence of Air (Vayu). Even if air is very subtle. And where there is Ether (Akash) there is Air (Vayu).

> In 9th Chapter of Gita, **“sarvagatah vayu”** has been said. Where there is Akash there is Vayu.
>
> यथाकाशस्थितो नित्यं **वायुः सर्वत्रगो** महान्।
>
> तथा सर्वाणि भूतानि मत्स्थानीत्युपधारय।।9.6।।
>
> **Meaning** *Just as the **extensive air, which is moving everywhere**, (being born of ether) ever remains in ether, likewise, know that all beings, who have originated from My Sankalpa, abide in Me.*
>
> > Hence when we go up (in space), where we say the place is devoid of air, Ether (Akash) is there, so air must be there.
> >
> > > **But let me give some example.**
> > >       Have you seen Tortoise or Fish, when one has Toroise or Fish as pet, and put someone on duty for 24 hours, that how many hours the tortoise sleeps and how many hours the fishes sleep?
> > >       In their movement itself they sleep. Like Horse does not lie down to sleep, lifting a leg - they sleep, so subtle is their sleep.
> > >       Similarly, Tortoise and Fish while swimming the reduction in speed they rest in that only and get sleep during that only.
> > >
> > > *Similarly, the places which we call devoid of Air, whose divine movements are very caring, they can manage with that type subtle air.*

*In 9th Chapter of Gita,*

**मयाऽध्यक्षेण प्रकृतिः सूयते सचराचरम्।**

**हेतुनाऽनेन कौन्तेय जगद्विपरिवर्तते।।9.10।।**

**Meaning:** Arjuna, under My aegis, Nature brings forth the whole creation, consisting of both sentient and insentient beings; it is due to this cause that the wheel of Samsara (Universe) is going round.

> **Param Brahman is the cause of Ether (Akash) and Param Brahman is the controller of all the energies.**
>
> ***Ether (Akash)*** is the cause of **Air (Vayu)** whereas **Ether (Akash)** is the source of all energies and there are four types.
>
> **Air** is the cause of **Fire** whereas Energy emanating from **Air** would be stronger than the one emanating from **Fire**
>
> **Fire** is the cause of **water** whereas Energy emanating from **Fire** would be stronger than the one emanating from **water**
>
> **Water** is the cause of **Earth** whereas Energy emanating from **Water** would be stronger than the one emanating from **Earth**

***Conclusion***

> **Hence from the above points we can conclude that Air is cause of Fire hence the rays generated from fire needs a medium to travel which is Air (Vayu) and present everywhere as there is no absolute vacuum exist. As Air (Vayu) do not have a tangible form that is why we feel Sun rays are faster. But the enabler of speed in Sunrays is Air (Vayu).**

Comment: You answered your own question?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu yeah! Is there any mistake? Please let me know.